# Broadcom poor wifi performance

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

My wifi has poor performance: often disconnects when the router is not next to it.

The *network card* is **BCM94352Z**, its *PCI-ID* is **[14e4:43b1] (rev 03)**. My kernel is version `4.4.0-59-generic.`

When I installed the OS, it automatically installed this driver for my wifi: `bcmwl-kernel-source`. According to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395),  `bcmwl-kernel-source` is the recommended driver for my card, [14e4:43b1] (rev 03).

Am I correct assuming reinstalling `bcmwl-kernel-source` from scratch, or trying a different driver would probably not improve the performance of my wifi?

Is there anything else I can do to improve the performance of wifi under linux?

Is there a specific command to update drivers like `bcmwl-kernel-source` to the latest version?

Comment: Are you using 16.04?

Comment: Elementary OS Loki 0.4, which is based on 16.04

Answer (score 1):

You can update the driver to the latest version by

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt install broadcom-sta-dkms
```

It will update the `wl` driver from 6.30.223.248 to 6.30.223.271.

But I am not sure that it can seriously improve anything. But it can, since Broadcom released this new blob for some reason.

As far as I know, there are no other drivers supporting this device on Linux.

Comment: Can I install broadcom-sta-dkms, without purging bcmwl-kernel-source, and then choose which driver to use using "Additional drivers"?
Should that cause any problem?

Comment: No, Additional Drivers do not know anything but `bcmwl-kernel-source`. That won't work I guess. But you can always revert it.